# is it possible to make a spline continous and smooth at both ends of a curve in gnuplot

Tags: spline, smoothing, continuous

I have data that are defined on a closed curve in 2D. The data is two columns x and y. x is the distance along the curve. y is in my case the gray value at the points x. Since the first and last y is the same, the curve is continuous. I want to approximate the curve with an acspline that is continuous (same value at the ends) and smooth (same derivative at the ends). Is that possible in gunplot?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to concatenate the data by itself, do the spline, and crop the middle of the concatenated curve.